# Local storage for 'clear cookies before exit'

Tags: flutter, local-storage

I have been developing an web app for our own company inside our own intranet.  The browser need to identify which computer it is and deliver appropriate information. I would have the app set an ID in local storage after typing the right password. It had been working fine until the sys admin decide to have 'clear all cookies before exit' in chrome. All the information is now gone. Of course the chrome is mangaed and those setting cannot be changed

I use flutter to program my app

Is there a storage that I can use that would not be affected by such 'clear cookies before exit' ?

Is it possible for flutter web to know the computer local ip ?  The app runs in an isolated environment without internet connection so cannot use package like ipify

Comment: As far as I know only server can get IP address. So you need add some function to backed to store IP and pass that to Flutter

Comment: The server maintains the connection , somehoe the clients IP are all the same, I figure that there must be some kind of nat.